# Questions about the constructors

Tags: c++

So, I was just reading about constructors initializers and why they are important.

So, in this regard, and I ask this only because it's not been explicitly mentioned and I don't want to learn things wrong.

So, in case of non-initializer constructors, for eg:

```
Student(int i, string s) {
    id = i;
    name = s;
}
```

When the constructor is invoked (automatically when an instance is created), do the members id and name first get initialized to the default values of an int and string respectively (and what are those default values?) before entering the body of the constructor and when the body is entered, they are overwritten with i and s respectively. Is my interpretation correct?

If that is the case, then initializer constructor like the following:

```
Student(int i, string s) : id(i), name(s) {}
```

reign supreme and should be used ALL THE TIME, right?

Why is the other constructor taught at all, in that case?

Comment: Initialization is complex: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Comment: The first one is probably taught first because it's easier to understand. Everyone's seen assignment before that point, but not the weird `:` syntax. You can then show them the `:` syntax once they understand what constructors are.

Answer (score 2):

Basic data types are uninitialized. Objects are created with their default constructor.

In your example, they are indeed overwritten by the new values. Depending on the types, this can be inefficient, as the work done in their default constructor may be wasted. In case of basic types, the compiler can optimize the initialization, and in case of `std::string` (which you should pass by const reference btw) it has a relatively cheap default constructor, compared to the cost of copying the string. So although the initialization list should be prefered style, not using it isn't super bad in this case.

The reason you have a constructor is because you may have more complicated logic than simply copying some data or assigning them to simple values. Try creating your own string class which takes a `const char *` parameter.

Comment: "Objects are created with their default constructor": If they have one, sure.

Comment: @Deduplicator You are right, I didn't think about PODs. Why not mention that in your comment to help me?

Comment: @KW123 When you pass a variable by value, it is copied. Why copy the string twice instead of once?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. The compiler will give them their default values. Numeric types are zero, strings to empty, vectors to empty, booleans to false and so on. That's why initializing outside the initialization list comes with a performance penalty: the compiler initializes first, then you assign values. Besides, initializing with {} also checks for a correct data-type. If you do this myInteger{2.5} you get an error, but if you do this myInteger = 2.5 you only put 2 in the variable. Regarding objects, the compiler will use their default constructor.

Comment: Your "default values" are describing value-initialization, but that isn't occurring here.

Answer (score 0):

```
sample::sample(int a)
{
    cout<< anim;
    anim = a;
    cout<< anim;
}
```

When calling

```
sample *Anim = new sample(10);
```

Output will be :

> 0 (grabage value assigned by the compiler . you are not supposed to read from an uninitialized variable, There is no rule that it will give 0 always, It will print some garbage value only)
>
> 10

```
sample::sample(int a) : anim(a)
{
    cout<< anim;
    anim = a;
    cout<< anim;
}
```

Output will be :

> 10 (value we are assigning)
>
> 10

In the former case value initialization happening at anim = a, ie datamember `int anim` is  created with some garbage value and initialised as `a`, in the later case intialization happening at creation of datamember.

Comment: The claim that a boolean defaults to true is totally wrong and worthy of a downvote.  This code actually causes undefined behavior.

Comment: No I am not claiming, I am explaining it for a current situation only, sorry for forgot to add that

Comment: It's still undefined behavior.  Weirder things can happen than simply having leftover garbage in the variable.  The value could appear to change on its own... or even worse.  You must never read from an uninitialized variable.